# Twilio sms gateway Change sender id as text

Tags: php, curl, twilio, sms-gateway

I am tring to use Twilio SMS gateway to send SMS to clients.Twilio API works good for me but i got struk in setting sender id.

Is there any possibities to set the sender ID as text ie., our business name (ex., Mycompany - i need to receive sms with this name)?

Answer (score 2):

Twilio evangelist here.

The short answer is that today we only allow you to use a Twilio phone number as the caller ID when sending text messages from Twilio.  You can read more about setting the caller ID for outgoing SMS messages [here](https://www.twilio.com/help/faq/sms/can-i-specify-the-phone-number-a-recipient-sees-when-getting-an-sms-from-my-twilio-app).

Hope that helps.

Comment: Can I change the sender id to text (Company name) and I don't want to receive sms with it. I just want to send.

Comment: No.  When using the Twilio REST API to send text messages, the API will only accept a Twilio phone number as the From parameter.

Comment: Why are you able to customize the caller ID for outgoing calls, but not SMS?